# Laravel 4: Input::has() + Input::get() vs. ($var = Input::get()) != null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When checking for presence of an input value and assigning it to a variable I see two ways to achieve this:

```
if(Input::has('id')) {
    $id = Input::get('id');
    // do some stuff
}
```

or maybe shorter `if(Input::has('id') && $id = Input::get('id')) {...}`, and

```
$id = Input::get('id');
if($id != null) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

respectively `if(($id = Input::get('id')) != null) {...}`.

Obviously the first method is more the Laravel way and might be more intuitive (at least to read) but on the one hand the second method seems to be faster as it involves less method calls while on the other hand being potentially slower for the needless variable assignment in the case of `id == null`.

So is there one way to prefer or maybe some other concerns I am not (yet) aware of?

Comment: I don't think that performance should be a factor when deciding about maintanable application design. Also, on a million calls, I doubt you'll save more than 1 millisecond so it would be a pointless optimization - thus, you can rule out the performance argument.

Comment: I would argue that the performance benefit from less method calls is a completely moot point. If you're at that level of micro-optimization, you should be using a framework in the first place. Calling two methods instead of one will provide no measurable benefit in performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would prefer always the readability of my code over milliseconds of faster code execution.

```
if(Input::has('id')) {
    $id = Input::get('id');
    // do some stuff
}
```

is possibly slower but this is so slightly that it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer you first way:

```
if(Input::has('id')) {
    $id = Input::get('id');
    // do some stuff
}
```

because speed of this is insignificant, you have more important things to optimise and speed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
if ($id = Input::get('id', null)) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

The second parameter of `get` is the default value to return if there is no `id` input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the default value for the `Input` like this

```
$id = Input::get('id'); // the default value will be null if you have no id parameter
if(!is_null($id)){ 
  // do your code here
}
```